AWS: Recursion Resource Creating with No Reason
Now I have a clip of AWS SAM template file:
Resources: 
  MyImageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  createThumb:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    # DependsOn: [MyImageBucket]
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      CodeUri: create_thumb/src/
      Description: Lambda function for creating thumbnail of the uploaded image.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 180
      Layers:
        - [REDACTED]
      Policies:
        - Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - s3:*
                - s3-object-lambda:*
              Resource: '*'
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
                - s3-object-lambda:WriteGetObjectResponse
              Resource: '*'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          S3_BUCKET_NAME: 
            Ref: MyImageBucket
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: 
              Ref: MyImageBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: images/
  # [... other resources]

And when I compile the YAML file, SAM said that the created resources has recursions dependencies.
When I removed the “Event” block on the create thumb function resource, it had no error and successfully created resources.
